# iAd Banner disappearing on 3.5", but shows on 4" screen?

Tags: ios, iad

I am doing a simple one view layout, calculator style app. I have multiple input fields, where values are entered, and a calculate button. All this works well. When I change size to 3.5" screen, the iAd banner I have at the bottom of screen disappears. When I switch back to 4", the banner is back. How do I lock down the banner to display at bottom of screen regardless of screen size? Thanks~

Comment: post the code that uses for iAd Banner

Comment: No code. Just using the drag and drop feature in the storyboard, and linking to the iAd framework.

Comment: if you use auto layout check out these, but my advice is to add an IBOutlet, connect it to iAd Banner and manage its position with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be happening because the Autolayout. Go to Storyboard, select the iAd view, then click on the segment "Pin" (third button on the bottom of Storyboard) and add the bottom Constrain.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had Autolayout off, but had to re-adjust some of the options in the View portion of the Inspector panel of the AdBannerView. Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you're using Autolayout. It takes a while to understand, but when you do it is extremely powerful for laying out flexibly for multiple screen sizes.

Anyway, assuming you are using Autolayout:

Here's my ViewController with the banner ad at the bottom
[image: Here's my ViewController with the banner ad at the bottom]

I select the banner and then click "Pin" - I then add the constraints that you can see in the image - click "Add Constraints".

[image: I select the banner and then click "Pin" - I then add the constraints that you can see in the image, and click "Add Constraints"]

Now, if I view how it would look on a 3.5" screen, it is still fixed to the bottom.

[image: Now, if I view how it would look on a 3.5" screen, it is still fixed to the bottom.]